# Variable name set to key and its value set to value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to set up a load of variables then loop though them adding them to an array with the key set as the variable name, something like below.

I am just not sure how you create the loop.

```
// create an array
$array = array();

// Set up Variable
$green  = "31d944";
$red    = "d92929";
$blue   = "1b43d9";
$pink   = "d96ad8";
$orange = "d98225";

// Loop though - not sure how this would work...
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
    $array[] = $varNmae => $green;
}

// Output something like below
$array['green']; // output '31d944'
$array['red'];  // output 'd92929'
$array['blue']; // output '1b43d9'
$array['pink']; // output 'd96ad8'
$array['orange']; // output 'd98225'
```

Comment: set up array directly, like `$array['green'] = "31d944"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`compact()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) is the opposite of [`extract()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) (extracting an associate array into the local symbol table), and is what you want to use.

```
$array = compact("green", "red", "blue", "pink", "orange");
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/ASUFb2e8).

Answer (score 5):

The function [`compact`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) does exactly this:

```
$array = compact('green', 'red', 'blue', 'pink', 'orange');
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the thinking in defining the variables and then adding them to an array, instead of just initialising the array?

```
// Can't you just use this?
$ary = array(
  'green' => '31d944',
  ...
  'orange' => 'd98225',
);
```

Could be looped with

```
foreach ($ary as $color => $val) {
  echo "{$color} is equal to {$val}";
}
```

Or accessed as

```
echo $ary['green'];
```